# Magento 1.7: Invalid block type error for custom widget

Tags: magento, widget

I am just trying to get a basic custom widget to work. I think I setup something wrong here. This is the exception i am getting:

```
2013-06-27T03:00:11+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Categoryproductslider_Block_Slider' in /home/sites/<url>/app/Mage.php:594
```

Here are the module/widget files with their paths

**app\etc\modules\PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Cms />
            </depends>
        </PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app\code\community\PaulCodes\Categoryproductslider\Block\Slider.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @author 
 * 
 */
class PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider_Block_Slider extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{

    /**
     * Produces slider html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $pageTitle = '';
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($headBlock) {
            $pageTitle = $headBlock->getTitle();
        }

        $html = '<a class="delicious" href="#" title="Add to del.icio.us">Del.icio.us</a>';

        return $html;
    }

}


?>
```

**app\code\community\PaulCodes\Categoryproductslider\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
      <PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider>
          <class>PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider_Block</class>
      </PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
      <PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider>
          <class>PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider_Helper</class>
      </PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider>
    </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app\code\community\PaulCodes\Categoryproductslider\etc\widget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
    <categoryproductslider_slider type="categoryproductslider/slider">
        <name>Category Product Slider</name>
        <description type="desc">A slider of products of a certain category</description>
    </categoryproductslider_slider>
</widgets>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your BLOCK layer XML tag identifier is `<PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider>` you have to refer to it with `type="PaulCodes_Categoryproductslider/slider"`

When you use Mage::getModel/Helper/Block/etc the first part of the access string is your XML tag identifier and the next part the path to your file in this folder layer.

I suggest you to put all your XML tag layer identifier in lowercase (see how standard magento modules are built)

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple. I just needed someone who has had more experience. Thank you also for the naming convention tip.